# Overloading >> Error C++

Tags: c++

Whenever I try to compile my program, I get a strange error. I have tried to look it up, and trying different methods of overloading it, but I still get errors.

```
istream& operator >> ( istream& in, MysteryCard& theMysteryCard ) 
{
  int value;
  in >> value;
theMysteryCard.change(value);
  return in;
}
```

---

All of my variables are right, and the functions work, but I do not know why it isn't working.

> 13 no match for `'operator>>'` in `'in >> value'`

The change function is public as well.

Comment: Please tell us the complete text of the error.  The code looks right to me, unless `MysteryCard::change(int)` is protected/private.

Comment: Maybe you should post that "strange" error.

Comment: Are you actually able to overload >> and << in the context of streams? I would have thought that the compiler is expecting you to be overloading the bitwise shift operators.

Comment: @LaceySnr: this is common C++ practice. Google "cout" for the most common use.

Comment: "*the functions work, but I do not know why it isn't working*" Us either, with that explanation...

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete program that demonstrates the problem. For more information about how to do that, and why it is important, see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks! I tend to just use C a lot of the type when I'm not doing force.com work, will remember that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that you're missing an include. Make sure you have `#include <istream>` and that you have either a using declaration for `std::istream` or a using directive for `namespace std`.

Comment: That fixed it, I can't believe i forgot to include it. Thanks so much!